# SSL Error Handler Webview PlayStore react-native

Tags: android, react-native

Mi aplicación con una versión de react-native 0.60.4, utiliza la librería reat-native-webview  se ha actualizado la versión de reat-native-webview de la 9.4.0 a la 10.6.0, al actualizar esa versión al querer actualizarla en la playstore no permitía adjunto la imagen del error

[image: SSL Error Handler]

Volví a la versión anterior a la 9.4.0, porque había leído en muchos foros que dicen que es mejor eliminar esa parte,( adjunto los enlances https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE/commit/85dadbfd7b31346b11ce642d4224e12561c8b169
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720753/android-google-play-warning-ssl-error-handler-vulnerability/35721678#35721678
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569047/how-can-load-https-url-without-use-of-ssl-in-android-webview/35618839#35618839 -> en los comentarios menciona que no funciono esta solución
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050741/webview-avoid-security-alert-from-google-play-upon-implementation-of-onreceiveds/36147896#36147896
)

por eso fue que regrese a la versión 9.4.0 y me sigue mostrando el mismo error, se supone que la versión 10.6.0 ya se ha agregado la solución a este error, sin embargo la playstore la sigue rechazando

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/commit/1bd596125599af1cbba6964876e305bb42a4e4cf?branch=1bd596125599af1cbba6964876e305bb42a4e4cf&diff=split

He revisado todos las urls de la aplicación y todas están correctamente con https

¿Alguien ha logrado resolver este error?

Comment: Aumentaste el número de versión antes de subir? Está todo actualizado?

Comment: Si se ha enviado la versión aumentada, todas las veces que se ha intentado subir

Comment: Ya revisaste el articulo que indica el reporte? ahí muestra como solucionarlo

Comment: Si en la documentación de PlasStore dice que hay que incluir SslErrorHandler.cancel () , revise el código de la librería react-native-webview (al ser una librería de terceros) y ahí se encuentra ese línea de código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para evitar la alerta de seguridad:

> SSL Error handler

> "Google Play Warning: SSL Error Handler Vulnerability"

Debes crear una clase CustomWebClient y sobreescribir el método `onReceivedError()`, aquí debes obtener el tipo de error y se generara un Dialogo en el cual debe preguntar al usuario si este desea continuar la carga de la página o cancela.

Por ejemplo en el caso de que la página a cargar en el `WebView` no tenga certificados de seguridad  el usuario podrá determinar cargar o no la página tomando el la responsabilidad.

```
private class CustomWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    ...
    ...
    ...


    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
        String message = "";
        switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
            case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
                break;
            case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                message = "The certificate has expired.";
                break;
            case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
                break;
            case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        message += "SSL Certificate Error, ¿Desea continuar?";


        builder.setTitle("SSL Certificate Error");
        builder.setMessage(message);
        //Acepta continuar la carga.
        builder.setPositiveButton("Continuar?", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                handler.proceed();
            }
        });
        //Cancela.
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                handler.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.create().show();
        
    }


}
```